# Sortable jumps outside container

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a problem with [Jonas von Andrian's jQuery Sortable plugin](https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/). When I try to move items, they first fly out of the `.row` and only after that I can move it normally.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(".items-container").sortable({
  containerSelector: ".items-container",
  itemSelector: ".item",
  containerPath: "> .row"
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-sortable/0.9.13/jquery-sortable-min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="items-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 panel panel-danger item">
        <div class="panel-heading">First panel</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, voluptates!</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 panel panel-warning item">
        <div class="panel-heading">Second panel</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, voluptates!</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 panel panel-success item">
        <div class="panel-heading">Third panel</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, voluptates!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View on JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/rakarideva/)

Comment: Can you please put your code in a [snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/) that illustrates the problem?

Comment: @wahwahwah https://jsbin.com/rakarideva/edit?html I have analog of this in my project

Comment: Just to confirm, are you using [Jonas von Andrian's jquery-sortable](https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/) and not the [jQuery UI sortable plugin](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/)?

Comment: @showdev Yes, I'm using Jonas von Andrian's jquery-sortable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using `itemPath` rather than `containerPath`, based on the ["Sort Tables" example](https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/#table).

The documentation is a bit murky to me. It says that `itemPath` is "The exact css path between the item and its subcontainers." But it seems to me to be the CSS path between the container and its items, which is what `containerPath` is supposed to define.

I have also added the `placeholder` option in order to apply Bootstrap styles to the placeholder element.

```js
$(".items-container").sortable({
  containerSelector: ".items-container",
  itemPath: "> .row",
  itemSelector: ".item",
  placeholder: '<div class="col-xs-4 panel placeholder"/>'
});
```

```css
.row .dragged {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 2000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-sortable/0.9.13/jquery-sortable-min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="items-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 panel panel-danger item">
        <div class="panel-heading">First panel</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, voluptates!</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 panel panel-warning item">
        <div class="panel-heading">Second panel</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, voluptates!</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 panel panel-success item">
        <div class="panel-heading">Third panel</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, voluptates!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! Now it works. And thank you for the corrections in my question. Next time I will be better.